# how to calculate a sequence's limit without know the sequence formula ($a_n=x$)?

Tags: calculus

how to calculate the sequence's limit, without knowing the sequence formula $a_n=x$?
I know only the limit of another expression with $a_n$.

for example:
$$ \lim ( a_n+5)^3 = 216 $$
$$ \lim | a_n-2| = 0 $$

how to get to $\lim(a_n) = something $ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lim a_n=L$.  Then by the fact that limits respect sums and products, or by the fact that $(x+5)^3$ is continuous in $x$, you basically have $(L+5)^3=216$ for which you can solve for $L$.

Answer (score 2):

For the second, you can use the triangle inequality $$|A-B|\le|A-C|+|C-B|$$ So with $A=2$, $B=L=\text{Lim}_{n\to \infty} a_n$, $C=a_n$ you have $$|2-L|\le|2-a_n|+|a_n-L|$$

The limit you are given shows that you can find $N$ with $|2-a_n|\lt \frac \epsilon2$ for all $n\gt N$ and likewise the limit of the $a_n$ shows that you have the second term on the right $\lt \frac \epsilon2$ for $n$ large enough.so that $|2-L|\lt \epsilon$ for large enough $n$, hence (since it is a constant) it is equal to zero.